# Django configuration in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm

After few years using Mac and Linux for my dev I have to pass on windows now. I have a project which run on docker-compose and that works very well on Mac and Linux but on windows I have some configuration problems with PyCharm.

If I run the docker compose by hand: works well
If I run the project threw the "run" or "debug" in pycharm: works well
But when I try to run the "manage.py command" threw pycharm I got this traceback:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

That would be just a small problem but it seems that Pycharm does not recognize django in the docker interpreter because all the django specific code is highlighted and the autocompletion doen't work anymore.
Basic example: if I use {% load ... %}, the load tag is not recognized.

It is definitly a problem in the configuration of pycharm but I can not find where it is.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not use WSL? Pycharm supports WSL as well.

Comment: hi ruddra. I don't really have the choice. The project is already existing on docker-compose i'm just hopping in it.

Comment: Use VS Code, it is much better than Pycharm.(I've used Pycharm for several years). It has excellent extensions for Docker.

Comment: I'm looking for fixing my problem not to change my IDE :)

Comment: that manifests thought wsl as well